# MVC Model validation on "HttpPostedFileWrapper"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

Can someone help me with model validation on a HttpPostedFileWrapper object?

**Model:**

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public HttpPostedFileWrapper BlahFile { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadBlahData(BlahModel blahModel) 
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**cshtml:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoadBlahData", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "blahhForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "uploadBlah" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload Blah Information</legend>
        @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.BlahFile, "Upload Blah file:")
        <input size="26" class="uploader" type="file" name="BlahFile" />
        <p><input class="ttButton" type="submit" value="Load Stuff" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Problem:**

1. Cannot see the "data-val*" attributes being added to the html.
2. Does not set the unobtrusive validation off (red border on input box)

**Notes:**

1. Other items in the Model are working fine with validation, its only the `<input type="file"/>` that seems to be having problems.
2. Comes into the action method fine - (i.e - i can access the InputStream if i want).
3. All scripts are referenced correctly (its working on normal text input's)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Thanks Adeel, manually adding the data-val* attributes worked.

Comment: <input size="26" class="uploader" type="file" name="BlahFile" data-val="true" data-val-required="The BlahFile field is required."/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone else coming across this question you can also do this -

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BlahFile, new { type = "file" }) %>
```

Comment: This is actually the best solution along with annotations in the model class. Thanks CSharper (sorry it took me so long to get back to you).

Answer (score 0):

you have not added any data attributes to your element. Add it like,

```
<input data-pk="1" size="26" class="uploader" type="file" name="BlahFile" />
```

and there is no support of validation of `<input type="file"`

Comment: Thanks Adeel, manually adding the data-val* attributes worked.